# Multiprocessing message transfer in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am very new to multiprocessing in Python, so please bear with me. I have a file that looks like this

```
from process_message_system import *
import sys


class Consumer(MessageProc):
    def main(self):
        super().main()
        while True:
            self.receive(
                Message(
                    'data',
                    action=lambda x: print(x)),
                Message(
                    'stop',
                    action=lambda: sys.exit()))


if __name__ == '__main__':  # really do need this
    me = MessageProc()
    me.main()
    consumer = Consumer().start()
    for num in range(1000):
        me.give(consumer, 'data', num + 1)
    me.give(consumer, 'stop')
```

So I have to develop a message processing system (`process_message_system.py`) which supposed to run the loop on each thread when the `Message` class receives `data` and the `action`. The `Message` should also flush the memory and exit when `me.give(consumer, 'stop')` is called.

As far as I understand this problem I came up with this in `process_message_system.py`

```
import multiprocessing
import time


class MessageProc(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def main(self):
        return

    def receive(self, *obj):
        while obj:
            print(obj)
            return obj

    def give(delf, obj, msg, *d):
        pass

    def run(self):
        pass

class Message:
    def __init__(self, msg, action):
        self.str = msg
        self.action = action
        self.temp = self.action()

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Returns things given to this object
        :return:
        """
        return 'The message is = %s and the action is = %s' % (self.str, self.temp)
```

I have no idea what to do after this. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**:

First file can be changed.

Comment: Is this homework?  Or can you modify the first file?

Comment: @JohnZwinck the first file can be changed